# How to find lim inf / lim sup

Tags: analysis

Let a$_n$ := $\frac {(n-1)(-1)^n}{n}$. Find lim sup a$_n$ and lim inf a$_n$.

I see that a$_n$ can either be $\frac {n-1}{n}$ when n is even or $\frac {-(n-1)}{n}$ when n is odd.

$\frac {n-1}{n}$ a$_2$ = $\frac {1}{2}$,  a$_3$ = $\frac {2}{3}$, a$_4$ = $\frac {3}{4}$.

$\frac {-(n-1)}{n}$ a$_2$ = $\frac {-1}{2}$,  a$_3$ = $\frac {-2}{3}$, a$_4$ = $\frac {-3}{4}$.

Clearly, the trend for is $\frac {(n-1)}{n}$  is increasing, $\frac {-(n-1)}{n}$ is decreasing. I feel like I have to use the monotone convergence theorem here, but I'm unsure how to continue. Also, would there be much of a difference if it was decreasing instead of increasing?

Edit: Added $\frac {-(n-1)}{n}$,

So to find lim sup, I would take a look at the $\frac {(n-1)}{n}$ and lim inf I would take a look at $\frac {-(n-1)}{n}$ right? Since sup is the least upper bound, so one must look at the increasing portion and inf is the greatest lower bound, so one must look at the decreasing portion? Could I get an example of how to do this?

Comment: (+1) This is pleasant, to see some work done along with the errors, when some people just throw out a question with no thinking. Keep it on this way Fox ! Regarding the problem, using a2,a3,a4 for both negative values and positive values is mistaken, look at Fred 's answer, it is better to talk about $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a_{2n}=\frac{2n-1}{2n} \to 1$ for $n \to \infty$

and

$a_{2n-1}=-\frac{2n-2}{2n-1} \to -1$ for $n \to \infty$.

Now suppose that $(a_{n_k})$ is a convergent subsequence of $(a_n)$ with limit $a$. Then $|a_{n_k}| \to |a|$.

But since $|a_n| \to 1$, we get $a=\pm 1$.

Consequence:

$\lim \sup a_n= \max\{-1,1\}=1$  and $\lim \inf a_n= \min\{-1,1\}=-1$